# Scalate ResourceNotFoundException in Scalatra

Tags: scala, scalate, scalatra

I'm trying the following based on scalatra-sbt.g8:

```
class FooWeb extends ScalatraServlet with ScalateSupport {
  beforeAll { contentType = "text/html" }
  get("/") {
    templateEngine.layout("/WEB-INF/scalate/templates/hello-scalate.jade")
  }
}
```

but I'm getting the following exception (even though the file exists) - any clues?

```
Could not load resource: [/WEB-INF/scalate/templates/hello-scalate.jade]; are you sure it's within [null]?

org.fusesource.scalate.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Could not load resource: [/WEB-INF/scalate/templates/hello-scalate.jade]; are you sure it's within [null]?
```

FWIW, the innermost exception is coming from `org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.getResource` line 1142: `_baseResource==null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got an answer from the scalatra mailing list. The problem was that I was starting the Jetty server with:

```
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.{Context,ServletHolder}
val server = new Server(8080)
val root = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS)
root.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new FooWeb()), "/*")
server.start()
```

I needed to insert this before `start()`:

```
root.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp")
```